# implement tesseract OCR in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2, tesseract

i want to implement handwriting recognition in my project

for example when user writes `A` on the screen, then screen should display `A`,

i had searched on google and so far i have found, `tesseract OCR`, but i am not getting what is `tesseract OCR` and how to implement this in my project can someone give demo tutorial of `tesseract OCR` and i don't know whether `tesseract OCR` is free or paid ...

***can someone give idea about `tesseract OCR` !!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one.
http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/

there are some old info.
https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR

Answer (score 2):

Tesseract is currently under [Apache License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License).  If you are planning a commercial application, that means you should include a copy of the Apache license, and you display a copy of the required copyright notice wherever your program displays copyright notices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)

Here is a link to someone who is using the engine in their android app.
http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Comment: It is free under Apache License.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this blog( http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/ ). It worked for me.

Comment: what is this ? i think this code is in php, and what this code doing ?

Comment: look at the download part: here is the compiled library  http://goo.gl/Z4Grl. And none of them are php coding.

Comment: dude it contains only .h file and some libraries, what should i do of this ?

Comment: you need to look into the .h files and call methods accordingly, like in which to pass image and how to get the letters out of it.. not an easy task if you are new to iOS. The implementation of .h files is in those libraries.