# Compiling tesseract for iOS

Tags: iphone, cross-compiling, tesseract

I am trying to compile tesseract 3.01 for iOS 4.0. Config script for tesseract fails with the following error:

```
checking for acos... yes
checking for asin... yes
checking for leptonica... yes
checking for pixCreate in -llept... no
configure: error: leptonica library missing
make: *** [config.status] Error 1
```

I have leptonica 1.68 built and have set the right LDFLAGS and LIBLEPT_LIBDIR values. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the prebuilt library itself. Have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9124709/641062